# Generate a log of all the installs on a system (whether apt-get/yum/pip/npm/...)

Tags: command-line, grep, history

Is there a command (or specific syntax for history command) that generates (to screen or file) a log of all the installs on a system (whether they were through apt-get/yum/pip/npm/...).

If possible, can it be sorted by the user who installed them so that it can be determined if they were installed Global or Local.

Thanks

Comment: @Serg thanks. Now I learnt that npm can install either locally or globally, but are all others (apt-get/pip/yum) always installed globally?

Answer (score 1):

Software installation always requires authentication with `sudo`, regardless of which package manager you use, thus you can check `/var/log/auth.log`. There are multiple ones most recent are in plain text, older are compressed into `gz` archive, such as `auth.log.4.gz`. Use `zgrep` for those files.

The format is the following:

```
Oct 18 14:38:01 eagle sudo:  xieerqi : TTY=pts/4 ; PWD=/home/xieerqi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks to your help I finally got it. I had to use zegrep though instead of zgrep because I wanted to zgrep to egrep a gzip (i.e. the command zegrep I discovered). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. `egrep -w 'apt-get|yum|pip|npm' *.* && zegrep -w 'apt-get|yum|pip|npm' *.gz`

Comment: In that case could you please mark my answer as accepted ? Thank you

Comment: I was just waiting to get the answer on the global vs. local portion. Do you know by chance?

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution. It's the log with the commands I want but not by user. If someone figures that part out, please leave a comment.

```
history | egrep -w 'apt-get|yum|pip' > /media/sf_Shared_with_Ubuntu/log
```